# CSS Image Flow with Variable Columns of Variable Width

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I would like to use CSS to define a set of images that flow to fill the width of a page. I'd like the images to vary depending on the width of the page between, say 100px and 125px. If the width of the page is 400px, there would be four columns of 100px wide images. If the page expands to 500px there would still be four columns, but the images would expand to 125px. If the page widens to 550px, the columns would increase to five, but now the images would reduce to 110px wide.

I can get my images to flow, but they stay the same size. I would like a solution where the images expand so the grid is fully justified all the time and extra columns are added when the elements reach a maximum size.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, max-content));
  gap: 10px;
}

.grid a img {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 125px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/150/100" alt="random">
  </a>

  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/150/100" alt="random">
  </a>

  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/150/100" alt="random">
  </a>

  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/150/100" alt="random">
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you investigated flex or gird with auto? And please show us the code you have with a description of what isn't working. We are happy to help but SO is for debugging code, not for getting it written from scratch. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Edited question to have code internal rather than referencing a different post. Thank you for keeping me on the straight and narrow!

Comment: What is the algorithm for this? e.g. if the overall width is 525px should there be 4 columns or 5? And why at 500px aren't there 5 columns? and so on. Is it just to maximise the column widths (rather than the number of coumns) within the 100px to 125px constraint?

Answer (score 0):

I used different **width values** in the image links but with this below codes you can align them properly in a row. Additionally i used fixed width and height in css codes and scaled fully with `background-size:100% 100%;`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

 .grid a img {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background-size:100% 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/300" alt="random">
  </a>

  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="random">
  </a>

  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="random">
  </a>

<a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" alt="random">
  </a>

  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" alt="random">
  </a>

  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/300" alt="random">
  </a>

<a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/700/300" alt="random">
  </a>

  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/300" alt="random">
  </a>

  <a href="https://google.com">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/900/300" alt="random">
  </a>


</div>
```